# Set a variable from an AOP advice

Tags: aop, aspectj

I use an `AOP` advice to convert a `User` object into a `Owner` object. The conversion is done in the advice but I would like to pass that `Owner` object to the caller.

```java
@Aspect
public class UserAuthAspect {
    @Inject
    private OwnerDao ownerDao;

    @Pointcut("@annotation(com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiMethod)")
    public void annotatedWithApiMethod() {
    }

    @Pointcut("execution(* *.*(.., com.google.appengine.api.users.User)) && args(.., user)")
    public void allMethodsWithUserParameter(User user) {
    }

    @Before("annotatedWithApiMethod() && allMethodsWithUserParameter(user)")
    public void checkUserLoggedIn(com.google.appengine.api.users.User user)
            throws UnauthorizedException {
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException("Must log in");
        }
        Owner owner = ownerDao.readByUser(user);
    }
}
```

A class with advised methods:

```java
public class RealEstatePropertyV1 {
  @ApiMethod(name = "create", path = "properties", httpMethod = HttpMethod.POST)
  public void create(RealEstateProperty property, User user) throws Exception {
        Owner owner = the value set by the advice
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the right way to do it, so feel free to comment. I created an interface `Authed` and its implementation `AuthedImpl`.

```java
public interface Authed {
    void setOwner(Owner owner);
}
```

Then I made `RealEstatePropertyV1` extends from `AuthedImpl`. I added a pointcut for all classes extending from `AuthedImpl` and also changed the pointcut so I can access to the target.

```java
@Pointcut("execution(* *..AuthedImpl+.*(..))")
public void extendsAuthedImpl() {
}

@Pointcut("execution(* *.*(.., com.google.appengine.api.users.User)) && args(.., user) && target(callee)")
public void allMethodsWithUserParameter(User user, Authed callee) {
}
```

Finally the advice uses all pointcuts:

```java
@Before("annotatedWithApiMethod() && allMethodsWithUserParameter(user, callee) && extendsAuthedImpl()")
public void checkUserLoggedIn(com.google.appengine.api.users.User user,
        Authed callee) throws UnauthorizedException {
    System.out.println(callee.getClass());
    if (user == null) {
        throw new UnauthorizedException("Must log in");
    }
    Owner owner = ownerDao.readByUser(user);
    callee.setOwner(owner);
}
```

Comment: Maybe I have missed something, but if `RealEstatePropertyV1` (part of your normal program) extends `AuthedImpl` (part of your aspect), doesn't it create a dependency between the program and the aspect? Do you need the `Owner` only in the aspect methods or in the normal program as well? Possibly it's just the name that confuses me: Is it a *UserAuthAspect* or an *inject owner* aspect?

Comment: You're right, I introduced a dependency between my program and the aspect. I need the `Owner` in the normal program. Basically I want my aspect to convert the `User` to a `Owner`, and then pass the `Owner` back to the normal program.

Comment: Actually `AuthImpl` is not part of the aspect. The aspect is just `UserAuthAspect`.